# mat2cell input argument error

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix of size 1134-by-1134 which I obtained from an image (using `imread` function). Now I want to break the image into 3-by-3 matrices for analysis. In order to do that I tried to use `mat2cell` as follows.

```
image = imread('C:\Users\ka\Desktop\test\step.png');  
X = mat2cell(image, [3], [3]);
```

But I got an error:

> Error using mat2cell (line 97)
>       Input arguments, D1 through D2, must sum to each dimension of the input matrix size, [1134  1134].'

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message really says it all: each of the inputs to `mat2cell` must sum to the size of the whole image, in this case 1134 (and 1134). For more information, see the [documentation](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html).

I believe what you want to do is:

```
sz = [1134 1134]; % size of input image
I = rand(sz); % make up some random data for testing
chunk_size = [3 3]; % your desired size of the chunks image is broken into
sc = sz ./ chunk_size; % number of chunks in each dimension; must be integer

% split to chunk_size(1) by chunk_size(2) chunks
X = mat2cell(I, chunk_size(1) * ones(sc(1),1), chunk_size(2) *ones(sc(2),1));
```

Let's check that the output is as desired:

```
size(X) % == sc
size(X{1}) % == chunk_size
sum(chunk_size(1) * ones(sc(1),1)) % 1134, as required
sum(chunk_size(2) * ones(sc(2),1)) % 1134, as required
```